# Why is the ClientApp/dist folder unexpectedly empty after Azure web app deploys via github actions?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am deploying a Single Page (angular) App integrated with a .Net Core 8.0 WebSite.  I deploy to an Azure Web App.

After the deployment the ClientApp/dist folder is empty.  It should contain the distribution components from my angular app.

It appears that the final deployment stage is removing, or refusing, the Client/dist folder contents.  It only affects the ClientApp/dist folder.  Other folders and files seem to be as I'd expect.

**Am I missing some setting/switch/or option that controls population of the Client/dist folder?**

The git actions yaml file is pasted lower down[1]

The rest of this post records why I think this...

**Stage 1**

**Evidence** The .Net Core app throws an exception stating it cannot find the index.html file. I used kudu to look at the wwwroot/ClientApp/dist folder.  It's empty.  I expected to see index.html and other files in there.

I traced index.html through the process.  I'm assuming the other files that belong in ClientApp/dist will follow the same path.

**Stage 2**

**Evidence** I enabled detail logging of the build and deploy process. In the output of the dotnet publish I see it report creating the runtime, main, polyfils and styles.  I infer that it's created index.html as well.

**Stage 3**

In the "Upload artifact for deployment job" output I see index.html mentioned

**Evidence** In the log I see
##[debug]File:/home/runner/.dotnet/myapp/ClientApp/dist/index.html was found using the provided searchPath

...and later...
##[debug]/home/runner/.dotnet/myapp/ClientApp/dist/index.html is less than 64k in size. Creating a gzip file in-memory to potentially reduce the upload size
##[debug]A gzip file created for /home/runner/.dotnet/myapp/ClientApp/dist/index.html helped with reducing the size of the original file. The file will be uploaded using gzip.

..and...
##[debug]File: 28/245. /home/runner/.dotnet/myapp/ClientApp/dist/index.html took 68.236 milliseconds to finish upload

**Stage 4**

In the deploy phase, sub phase "Download artifact from build job" I see index.html mentioned again

**Evidence** In the log output I see...
##[debug]File: 92/245. /home/runner/work/[Redacted]/[Redacted]/ClientApp/dist/index.html took 263.048 milliseconds to finish downloading.

That last log line leads me to expect the index.html file to show up in wwwroot/ClientApp/dist when I use kudo to inspect the deployed files.

**Conclusion**

**It looks as though the 'Download artifact from build job' stage has 'lost' the entire contents of the ClientApp/dist directory.**

**AFAICT files are ONLY missing from the specific directory ClientApp/dist.  There are other .html, .js, and .css files that have faithfully arrived in their expected places.**

*This is my first experience with Azure I'll probably need hand holding.*

**[1] git actions yaml file**

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - develop-redacted

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Set up node 16.20.2
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
            node-version: '16.20.2'

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish ./NetCoreWebsite/NetCoreWebsite.csproj -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.redacted }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.redacted }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.redacted }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'develop-redacted'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
```

Comment: Please share your github `.yml` file and if possible GitHub repository.

Comment: Added the github yaml file.  I cannot share the repository.  It's the original generated yaml file plus a mod to specify use of node 16.20.2, and a mode to the dotnet publish to specify the website as the project to publish

Comment: Can you please share you directory structure??

Comment: My directory structure is, essentially, identical to your answer below.  The only difference is that my Angular project is in ClientApp rather than angular-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Am I missing some setting/switch/or option that controls population of the Client/dist folder?**

- You were not building the `dist` folder in the using command `npm run build`
- You need to upload after building.
- In you `.yml` file you were only selecting the node version, no operations were being done after node selection.

This Worked for me.

**#my directory :**

```
Webapp/
│
├── .github/
│   └── workflows/
│       └── main_dotnetwithangualr.yml
│
├── WebApplication2/
|   ├── angular-app/
|   │   ├── src/
|   │   │   └── ...                             
|   │   ├── angular.json
|   │   ├── package.json
|   │   └── ...
│   ├── Controllers/
│   │   └── ...               
│   ├── Models/
│   │   └── ... 
│   ├── Properties/
│   │   └── ...                 
│   ├── Views/
│   │   └── ...                 
│   ├── wwwroot/
│   │   └── ...                
│   ├── appsettings.json
│   ├── Program.cs
│   └── WebApplication2.csproj
│
└── WebApplication2.sln
```

[image]

**`main_dotnetwithangualr.yml`:**

```yaml
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - dotnetwithangualr

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Set up Node.js version  
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3  
        with:  
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test  
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
        working-directory: WebApplication2/angular-app/  # building `dist`, using `package.json` as it is available in "WebApplication2/angular-app/" path I added working directory.

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: angular
          path: ./WebApplication2/angular-app/dist/  # uploading files and folders created inside `dist`

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          
      - name: Download artifact from angular build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: angular
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'dotnetwithangualr'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_E48F4EC67FB14F22A7CD2D3AA9C7BDF5 }}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

**`dist` in local :**

[image]

**uploaded files on azure :**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a fabulous answer.  Thank you so much for taking the tine and trouble to be so detailed.  It turns out that my .csproj file had enough smarts inside it to run the npm build.  Adding explicit steps to the yml file to upload and deploy the angular project were what finally fixed it for me.

Thank you again